# How to get 'svn diff' output from svnkit as nicely encapsulated objects instead of as an OutputStream

Tags: svn, svnkit

For example, svn logs can be obtained encapsulated as `SVNLogEntry` using the [`SVNLogClient`](http://svnkit.com/javadoc/org/tmatesoft/svn/core/wc/SVNLogClient.html).

However using the [`SVNDiffClient`](http://svnkit.com/javadoc/org/tmatesoft/svn/core/wc/SVNDiffClient.html) I see the possibilty of only getting the diff as an `OutputStream`.

Getting the diff as a collection of objects will save me from doing a lot of string processing trying to access common fields in each diff